# Why is there a 25 entity group limit for transactions in Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I understand why there is a write throughput limit of 1 second per entity group (strong consistency requirements for replication, etc). I don't understand why you are limited to 25 different entity groups in a transaction. Presumably this is for some other consistency/performance reason but I am having trouble understanding what that may be. What is the reason behind this limitation?